# Getting base url of my project

Tags: php, file, http, uri

I have an XML file that I use to create a PHP object. I then want to simply print out the image however I am getting the error 'Not allowed to load local resource'.

To get the image URL I have set a variable

```
$root = ( __DIR__ );
```

And then append that to the path in my XML file.

```
$parseXML = simplexml_load_file('chicken.xml');

$img_url =  $parseXML->picture;

$imgg = $root . '/' . $img_url;
```

This now gives me the current path which is

C:\wamp\www\recipesUpdated/images/MarinoWebsite.jpg

If I copy and paste this into my browser it displays the image but won't work when I echo it in an img src.

Is there a way of getting the path just to
  \recipesUpdated/images/MarinoWebsite.jpg

Without the C:\wamp etc ?

Thank you!

Comment: is this because you're getting back slash in `C:\wamp\www\recipesUpdated` ?

Comment: It works fine in my browser with the URL it prints. Just not in my img src

Comment: As you rightly point out, "C:\wamp\www\recipesUpdated/images/MarinoWebsite.jpg" is not a valid URI. The image src attribute needs a valid URI. So if you could explain why you create an invalid URI in the first place, this would be helpful to answer your question. Otherwise I must admit it's not really clear to me what you're asking about albeit I do see that what you describe does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You get path to image on your local computer, and browser not allowed to load this path.

Url must contain web server address or be relative

Example:

```
http://localhost/recipesUpdated/images/MarinoWebsite.jpg
```

or

```
/recipesUpdated/images/MarinoWebsite.jpg
```

For your question, try to set variable $root to empty string or your web server address.

Comment: How do I set it to the web server address? /recipesUpdated/images/MarinoWebsite.jpg is what I am trying to achieve